# What's the equivalent of this Ruby code in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, dictionary, hash

```
#Ruby Code
si=1
gw=0
linkedNodes=[{1=>2},{1=>0}]
puts "found node" if linkedNodes.include?({si=>gw})
```

I'm trying to figure out if there's way to do something like this in Python. I'm searching an array of hashes for a match on the complete hash, which is incredibly easy to do in Ruby using the

```
include?()
```

method. I found a lot of information about searching lists for hash by key or by value but I'm trying to match the entire hash (key and value). I read about a filter option using a lambda but that quickly turned into a hot mess when I started getting exceptions and playing around with try: except: blocks.

Comment: This is not a valid ruby code per se in the first place.

Comment: There was a typo in the ruby example, it's fixed and valid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant `linkedNodes = [{1 => 2}, {1 => 0}]`, this is a literal translation to python:

```
>>> si=1
>>> gw=0
>>> linkedNodes = [{1:2},{1:0}]
>>> if {si:gw} in linkedNodes:
...   print("found node")
#⇒ found node
```

Comment: Your assumption was correct, I had a typo in my ruby example. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Common or garden variety Python doesn't have anything like that. You'd do it in two steps: first check the key, then the value:

```
if si in linkedNodes and linkedNodes[si] == gw:
    # do whatever
```

`and` is short-circuiting, so if `si` is not a key in `linkedNodes`, `linkedNodes[si] == gw` is not evaluated; you can't get an error trying to access that element in that case.

If you want to do so, you could create a `dict` subclass where `in` behaves that way (or does so optionally). This I'll leave as an exercise.

Comment: The problem is that linkedNodes is an array that has hashes in it. So I don't think I can search in linkedNodes for si because linkedNodes looks like [{1:2},{1:0}]

Comment: Ah, yeah, you'd have to search that manually, and apply that test to each item in it.